# Python is installed but is not working in terminal

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I installed Python 3 using the Cygwin terminal. There were no issues during installation.
I get this:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

and

```
$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.8 
/usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

But neither of

```
$ python3 $ python3 main.py $ python3 --version
```

give any output. I have done this the same way before on the same computer and it worked fine. What did I do wrong this time? Or forgot to do?

Comment: Could you start a new terminal and try again?.
If that not works, could you do: ```echo $PATH``` and write the result?
Could you try: ```/usr/bin/python3 --version``` and write the output?

Comment: $ /usr/bin/python3 --version makes no output. The echo $PATH gives a far too long output to include here. What part of it would be interesting to see? To start a new teminal makes no difference.

Comment: we would like to check with ```/usr/bin/python3 --version``` if python executable is there and is working and with ```echo $PATH``` we want to make sure that /usr/bin or /usr/bin/python is inside the PATH

Comment: Here is the beginning:  `$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts:` There is no `/usr/bin/python` in the output.

Comment: Try `py`, `python`, `Python`, `python2`, `python3.8`

Comment: It's probably just `$ python`.

Comment: Can you try `strace python3 --version` and paste result ?

Comment: @Philippe python3 is a simlink. Strace need the original program `strace /usr/bin/python3.8.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an alias to attach python to the common name "python3". In your Cygwin terminal write:

```
$ alias python3=$(which python3.6)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried that one with no success.

Comment: Have you tried to run $ python3.6 or $ python3.8 ?

Comment: Yes. No result.

Comment: If it's possible try to reinstall Cygwin packages, and check that next packages installed: 
\All\Devel\make
\All\Devel\gcc-core
\All\Devel\gcc-fortran
\All\Devel\gcc-g++
\All\Python\python36
\All\Python\python36-pip

Answer (score 0):

python3 should be a link managed by `alternatives` pointing to `python3.8`

```
$ alternatives --display python3
python3 - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 36
/usr/bin/python3.7 - priority 37
/usr/bin/python3.8 - priority 38
Current `best' version is /usr/bin/python3.8.
```

that belongs to `python38` package

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/python3.8
python38-3.8.7-3
```

verify that `python38` is correctly installed

```
$ cygcheck -c python38
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python38             3.8.7-3        OK
```

and that there are no issue on the dependency

```
$ cygcheck /usr/bin/python3.8.exe
D:\cygwin64\bin\python3.8.exe
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\libpython3.8.dll
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll
      D:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
```

More likely you need to re-install `python38` or one of the needed libraries

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll /usr/bin/cygintl-8.dll /usr/bin/cygiconv-2.dll  /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
cygwin-3.1.7-1
libgcc1-10.2.0-1
libiconv2-1.16-2
libintl8-0.19.8.1-2
```

be sure to stop `all` Cygwin `processes` before re-installing the packages; specially any  running service

Comment: Thank you @matzeri for your detailed answer. The command `alternatives` does not exist when I try it, but all your other commands give exactly the same output as yours above. When I look in the Windows File explorer I find Python 3.6 and 3.8 in the `c:/cygwin64/lib` folder. Is that correct?

Comment: `python38` requires `alternatives`. Are you using the Cygwin setup for installation ?  https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python38.html . `/usr/lib/python3.8` should be a directory   https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/python38/python38-3.8.7-3

Comment: I tried to set up all this on my other laptop instead and it all works well on first attempt. Confusing.

Comment: have you tried installing `alternatives` and re-installing `python38` ?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3` ? Does `python3.8 --version` works ?